# Why doesn't this python code run infinite times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

```
a = 3
for i in range(a):
    print(a, end = ' ')
    a +=1
```

It just produces the output as:

```
3 4 5
```

I don't understand this because since *a* is being incremented each time, the loop should run forever.Or is it that the iterable range is generated only once?

Comment: Even if `a` was mutable, `range(3)` was calculated before `a += 1`

Comment: `expr` is evaluated *only once* when you call `for x in expr:`, it's "locked in".

Comment: If you take a picture of your car, and then you crash your car, will the car in the picture turn into a car wreck? Of course it won't. So why would you expect the `range(a)` to change just because `a` changed?

Comment: use a `while` loop if you need that

Comment: @Aran-Fey in Back To The Future is does. Change `a`, drive in the Delorean at 88 miles an hour: done.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  do not use Delorean as side effects on range iterations .. can't find the PEP quite now, but there should be one.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes, this is a duplicate

Comment: Got the answer. But didn't get that what was wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how the program source code is interpreted. `range(a)` will be executed before the body of the loop, producing an iterable object which yields `3, 4, 5`. `a` will be modified later but it will not affect `range(a)` cause it has already been executed. The following *will* do what you want, but it's kind of a silly program now:

```
a = 3
i = a
while i < a:
   print(a, end = ' ')
   a += 1
   i += 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing c/c++/c#  `for` syntax with python.

In c/c++/c# you have a conditional inside the for syntax:

```
for (var i= 0; i<100;i++) # this is checked each time you come back here, incrementing
                          # the i will skip some runs and change how often the for is done
```

Pythons `for` is more a `foreach`:

```
for i in range(3):
```

==>

```
foreach(var k in new []{0,1,2}) # it takes a fresh "k" out every time it comes here
{ ... }
```

if you modify `k` it will still only run 3 times.